# Any examples of life forms on Earth that could have survived on Mars or Moon?

Tags: life

Do we know of any living forms on Earth that could continue to live on Mars?

Comment: Under the current conditions and without an athmosphere? Hardly imaginable.

Comment: Yes, under current conditions and without an atmosphere.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, research studies that were conducted have found that [methanogens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methanogen) (microorganisms) are able to survive in conditions similar to Mars ([reference](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2633741/Could-Earth-superbug-live-MARS-One-planets-simplest-oldest-organisms-survives-Martian-environment.html)). Another study conducted has also concluded that some lichen and cyanobacteria is also capable of survival.  Surprisingly, they were also found to be active ([reference](http://www.planetary.org/blogs/guest-blogs/20120515-earth-life-survive-mars.html)).

There is speculation now on whether organisms from earth have been accidentally transported to Mars on the Mars Curiosity Rover which would be funny or a cause of concern, depending on how you look at it ([reference](http://rt.com/usa/160636-mars-curiosity-rover-bacteria/)).

Comment: Interestingly, methanogenes are even more useful for terraforming Mars than plants, because they accelerate greenhouse effect.